# Django рендер шаблона с react с роутингом

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, django-template

Ситуация следующая

Есть джанго приложение и фронт на реакте с роутингом

После сборки фронта я пытаюсь его рендерить как шаблон джанго и таким образом хостить

Соответственно, url и views выстроены так:

index/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from api import urls as api_urls
from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api_urls)),
    path('', views.index),
]
```

---

Когда я запускаю джанго приложение и гружу главную страницу по адресу `/`, и весь роутинг работает нормально, например на `/home` заходится нормально

Но как только я обновляю страницу на уже измененном адресе (тот же `/home`), браузер, естественно, посылает запрос на джанго сервер, а не срабатывает вутренний роутинг страницы, поэтому возвращается `404 not found`

Как с этим бороться?

---

P.S. Я предполагаю, что такое лучше делать с помощью серверов типа `nginx` и ему уже указывать, как хостить реактовское приложение, и он уже будет смотреть, что брать из жданго, а что брать как статический запрос, но мне хотелось бы все же добить его как шаблон джанго

Comment: Просто принимайте все возможные урлы? `path('<path:path>', views.index)`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, чет я забыл про это))

Comment: @andreymal но еще странновато то, что с Vue.js работало и без этого